# Inserting console output data into a Temp Table from pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the below pl/sql which fetches and prints multiple columns from different tables and prints on console. However for a real time scenario, i need all the data to go into a temporary table. SO that user can do a Select * from the temp table and fetch the data retrieved. Can someone please confirm how can I do that?

```
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
    Declare
    Cursor crsr(companyschema varchar2) is Select Person_Id,Birth_Name from salesdemo.PER_PERSON;
    personId number;
    bioBirthName varchar2(128);
    personalBirthName varchar2(128);
    usersSysId varchar2(256);
    legalEntity number;
    territoryId number;
    country varchar2(256);
    BEGIN
      FOR c_schema IN
      (SELECT company_schema
      FROM sap.sf_companies c,
        sap.sf_feature_map m
      WHERE c.company_id = m.company_id
      AND m.feature_id   = 326  
      ) 
      LOOP
      BEGIN

      open crsr(c_schema.company_schema);
        if crsr%isopen then
        loop
        begin
          fetch crsr into personId, bioBirthName;
          exit when crsr%notfound;
          dbms_output.Put_line('Schema '|| c_schema.company_schema);
          dbms_output.Put_line('PersonId '|| personId);
          dbms_output.Put_line('Bio Birth Name '|| bioBirthName);
          execute immediate 'select Birth_Name  from '||c_schema.company_schema||'EMP_PERSONAL_INFO_T where person_id = :1' INTO personalBirthName using personId;
          dbms_output.Put_line('Personal Birth Name '|| personalBirthName);
          execute immediate 'select users_sys_id  from '||c_schema.company_schema||'EMP_EMPLOYMENT_INFO where person_id = :1' INTO usersSysId USING personId;
          dbms_output.Put_line('UsersSysId '|| usersSysId);
          execute immediate 'select company  from '||c_schema.company_schema||'EMP_JOB_INFO_T where users_sys_id = :1 ' INTO legalEntity USING usersSysId ;
          dbms_output.Put_line('Legal Entity '|| legalEntity);
          execute immediate 'select territory_id  from '||c_schema.company_schema||'FO_LEGAL_ENTITY_T where internal_code =:1' INTO territoryId USING legalEntity;
          dbms_output.Put_line('Territory Id '|| territoryId);
          execute immediate 'select territory_name from '||c_schema.company_schema||'Territory where territory_id = :1 ' INTO country USING territoryId;
          dbms_output.Put_line('Country '|| country);
          EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            IF SQLCODE = -00942 THEN
              CONTINUE;
            END IF;
        end;
        end loop;
        end if;
      close crsr;
          EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            IF SQLCODE = -00942 THEN
              CONTINUE;
            END IF;
      END;
      END LOOP;
    END;
```

Comment: You could use a Global Temporary Table.

Comment: Thanks @LalitKumarB , but can u please help me with syntax or an excerpt for the script in my question?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Inserting console output data into a Temp Table from pl/sql

The output you see on the console is from the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` procedure. If you want to insert the same out put into a table to use it for further processing, I would suggest a **Global Temporary Table**.

The data in a global temporary table is private, such that data inserted by a session can only be accessed by that session. The session-specific rows in a global temporary table can be preserved for the whole session, or just for the current transaction. The `ON COMMIT` clause indicates that the data should be deleted or preserved at the end of the transaction.

- ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS
- ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS

In your case, create the **GTT** once, and then in your **PL/SQL** code, insert the rows into the GTT.

For example,

```
INSERT INTO company_gtt
   VALUES
(c_schema.company_schema, personId, bioBirthName, personalBirthName ....)
```

See more examples here http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/temporary-tables.php

Comment: @ShreyanshShiwam, thanks for your feedback. Please mark it as answered, it would help others.